# Asymptotics for a sum involving GCD and multiplicative order

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\mathrm{ord}_{n}(a)$ be the least positive integer $d$ such that $n\mid a^{d}-1$. I wanted to know if  for some choice of $y=y(x)$, one can obtain asymptotics for the sum $$f(x,y):=\sum_{a\le y}\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\ \gcd(n,a)=1}}\frac{\gcd(n,\mathrm{ord}_n(a))}{\mathrm{ord}_n(a)}$$ where $n$ and $a$ are positive integers and $y\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty.$

Comment: The term in the sum depends only on $n$ and $a \bmod n$, so $f(z, n) = \Theta(z)$. Should the question be about $f(n, n)$ as a function of $n$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor a runs over all positive integers till z and I have edited that in the question

Comment: I assumed that already.

Comment: When a function depends on two variables, there are different possible asymptotic regimes. Please specify.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I want asymptotic in terms of z and n is a fixed positive integer.

Comment: Then you sum up the values of a certain $n$-periodic function, thus the asymtotics is $cz+O(1)$. Is this what you ask for?

Comment: @FedorPetrov You are right. I didn't realise this earlier. I have edited the question again and am extremely sorry for inconvenience caused.

Comment: $$\frac{f(x,y)}{y} \approx \sum_{n \le x} \sum_{\substack{a\le n\\ \gcd(n,a)=1}}\frac{\gcd(n,\mathrm{ord}_n(a))}{\mathrm{ord}_n(a) n}$$ so you probably really want to ask about the sum on the RHS. The inner sum has an upper bound of $\frac12$ achieved when $n$ is a power of $2$ or $3$; if it has a lower bound then it's probably something like $\Theta(n^{-1 - \varepsilon})$